# Create a combination from 4 different arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, combinations

I am pulling in football players from an API, who each have the corresponding values: `first_name`, `second_name`, `id`, `price`, `position`, `total_points`. My aim is to show all the combinations of 15 players that when summed up, is equal to or less then a budget set.

Each combination must have a total of 15 players. Which must be based on the following positions : 3 Forwards, 5 Midfielders, 5 Defenders and 2 Goalkeepers - whilst total price `<= budget`.

I am not quite sure the best way to do this, but I have gone down the following route: I'm attempting to create a hash matching `id => price` to show all player prices. However, I then realised for the combo I need to sort players by `position`. From the API call, `positions` are in the form of `1`, `2`, `3`,`4`. So I have created 4 separate hashes containing a list of all the players in each position. However, since the price is needed for the combinations, Rather then `second_name` I need to use `price => position`. But this doesn't seem to be working due to my `/10.to_f` calculation. I'm assuming I should do the `/10.to_f` at a later point to avoid this. This calculation is needed as currently prices that get pulled in are *47* rather then *4.7.*

```
def index
    require 'net/http'
    require 'json'
    url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    object = JSON.parse(response)
    elements = object["elements"]

    # PULL IN PLAYER DETAILS
    id = elements.map{ |x| x["id"]  }
    first_name = elements.map{ |x| x["first_name"]  }
    second_name = elements.map{ |x| x["second_name"]  }
    team = elements.map{ |x| x["team"]  }
    position = elements.map{ |x| x["element_type"]}
    price = elements.map{ |x| x["now_cost"]  }
    total_points = elements.map{ |x| x["total_points"]  }

    # TOTAL PRICE OF COMBINATION MUST NOT EXCEED BUDGET
    budget = 100

    # CREATE METHOD TO SUM BOTH PRICES AND POINTS FOR GIVEN COMBINATION
    def add_up(combo, ht, hd)
      t, d = combo
      ht[t] + hd.values_at(*d).sum
    end

    # DIVIDE PRICES BY 10
    divided_price = price.collect { |n| n / 10.to_f }

    position_hash = second_name.zip(position)

    # LIST OF ALL PLAYERS BY POSITION
    forward_prices = position_hash.to_h.select { |key, value| value == 4 }.keys
    midfielder_prices = position_hash.to_h.select { |key, value| value == 3 }.keys
    defender_prices = position_hash.to_h.select { |key, value| value == 2 }.keys
    goalkeeper_prices = position_hash.to_h.select { |key, value| value == 1 }.keys

    # MAX NUMBER OF POSITION TYPE
    forward_combo = forward_prices.combination(3).to_a
    midfielder_combo = midfielder_prices.combination(5).to_a
    defender_combo = defender_prices.combination(5).to_a
    goalkeeper_combo = goalkeeper_prices.combination(2).to_a

  end
```

Now I just need to combine the 4 combinations at the bottom to give me my combinations. I would have gone for `.product` but assuming that can't be done with 4 arrays.

Comment: Do not define methods with `def` inside of a method. This does not do what you think it does if you're for example coming from JavaScript as it defines the method on the outside object. You need start here by moving this code out of the controller and breaking it into sensible peices. If your method needs line comments inside the method its doing way to much.

Comment: Extract this out into a class and have each method just do one job - one method does the HTTP call. One parses out X. One combines X with Y. This is how you write code that can be tested, reasoned about and maintained. You have asked multiple questions about this same feature and its pretty obvious that you're just banging your head against the wall instead of structuring the code in a way that will make it easier to complete the task.